# Methods that return delegates with .net2

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, .net-2.0, anonymous-delegates

I've been working in .net 4 and really enjoying the ability to return bespoke functions from a single method e.g:

```
public Func<object, object> FunctionBuilder(object o) 
{ /*build functions, woo*/ }
```

...however this appears very difficult if not impossible to do within .net2 since `Func` appears in .net3.5(?) and something like:

```
public delegate<object> FunctionBuilder(object o) 
{ /*nope*/ }
```

...is not valid syntax..

Is it even possible to return bespoke functions from a method within .net2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it even possible to return bespoke functions from a method within .net2?

Absolutely, but you need to return a specific delegate type.

The simplest thing is probably to declare your own generic delegates, e.g.

```
public delegate TResult ProjectFunc<T, TResult>(T arg)
```

And then:

```
public ProjectFunc<object, object> FunctionBuilder(object o)
```

Then if/when your project moves to .NET 3.5, you can just remove `ProjectFunc` and use `Func` instead. We've [taken this exact approach in Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Delegates.cs) (which actually now uses .NET 3.5 anyway) and it's worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this construct.

```
delegate object MyDelegate(object);

MyDelegate FunctionBuilder()
{

}
```